# Bootstrap is a little bit widder than 100%

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, horizontal-scrolling

At first, i thought it was the navbar. But now im lost.

What i mean is that it scrolls a bit to the right, it has some horizontal scrolling which i do not want

Here is my link:
http://buscolapaz.com/

I really don't know what I am doing wrong. I am using bootstrap.

I have already tried adding

```
     body {
  position: relative;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   width: 100%;
}
```

with no avail. I've checked the width and apparently everything is the same width even the nav-bar.
When horizontal scrolling only the nav-bar seems to be 100% width thou

Comment: I don't see any horizontal scrollbar when I visit it.  More details please.

Comment: The js wasn't linked correctly. Somehow that helped